# when i logout the url not hold http it comes after refresh

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3, http-status-code-500

these happen because of using
$this->session->destroy();
to destroy the logged-in user information
but it destroys the HTTP segment so the page must be reloaded to display.

Answer (score 0):

after i change
$this->session->destroy();
to
$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
it works fine